# Variable NSTextCell width / count per ROW -- is it possible?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa-touch, cocoa

For both Mac OS and IOS I'm looking for a method that would allow for a table to contain a variable number of `NSTextCell` objects per row -- think the merged cells in a spreadsheet, or in a table in MS-Word.

Example: row 1 of a table might have one very wide cell, whereas row 2 might have 50, and row three might have 10.  Typically 10-30 rows, total.  The entire table must be capable of sitting in a scrollable view.

Clearly a cell-based `NSTableView` won't permit this, and I suspect that a view-based `NSTableView` can't either: it permits "empty" or "missing" cells, but I couldn't find evidence that a cell could cross "column" boundaries, as I require.  It doesn't seem subclassing is an option.

I've looked at `NSMatrix`, which also imposes a grid of items.

I've looked at `NSCollectionView`, but it seems grid-based, too.

I've looked at using an HTML "TextTable" -- I suspect this may be a ton of work, a poor substitute for an actual UI-based table, and yield low performance.

Do I really have to just create a custom view, add NSCell objects myself, and manage the entire process of drawing / activating editing using a single editable cell myself?  I have done this before (on other platforms) for very complex visual tables, and it isn't fun...

One desperation move I thought of was to create multiple single-row `NSTables` within the same `NSScrollView`, allowing them to all scroll together.  (there may be dozens of cells per row, but only around 2 dozen rows TOTAL).  It may be hackish, but it might be seamless to the end-user.

One final possibility is that someone has already crafted an available Cocoa source code solution.

Any other desperate souls that have trodden down this path and lived to tell the tale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSTableView` can be made to do this I believe. See e.g. http://gigliwood.com/tabletester/

Comment: WOW.  What an answer. Apple Developer Support had told me it couldn't be done.  I can't thank you enough!